# Real analysis: function and sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I have a hard time understanding the following theorem: Suppose that D$\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an unbounded above domain of the function f: that is, D contains arbitarily large values. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)=L$ if and only if for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ in D that diverges to plus infinity, that is, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to L.

My book doesn't provide an example which makes it even harder to understand. Does it have to hold for every sequence that diverges to infinity? And is one able to show that it holds for all those sequences? Do you then substitute the sequence within the function? I don't understand. I hope someone can help me or give a clear example. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of the Theorem was given in the @jooi's answer. I will give two examples.

**Remark:** We can use this theorem to prove the existence (or to calculate) the limit of a function or to prove that a function doesn't have a limit. In the first case, we work with arbitrary sequences; in the second case, we work with suitable particular sequences.

> **Example 1:** Take $D=(0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$. Prove that
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$

*Solution:* Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $D$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$$
As $\{x_n\}$ goes to $\infty$, $\{\frac{1}{x_n}\}$ goes to $0$. Thus,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x_n}\frac{1}{x_n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}=0\cdot0=0$$
It follows from the Theorem that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$

> **Example 2:** Take $D=(0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Prove that
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$$
>   doesn't exist.

*Solution:* Assume that the limit does exist. Then, there exists $L\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)=L$$
Notice that $\big\{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\big\}$ diverges to $\infty$ and $\big\{\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi n\big\}$ diverges to $\infty$ too. So, by the Theorem,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)=L\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)=L$$
Since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)=-1$$
we conclude that $L=1$ and $L=-1$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, there is no $L\in \mathbb{R}$  such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)=L$$
In other words, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I now see that it isn't that hard at all:)

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$. Now for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $M$ such that
$$
x > M \implies |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon\,.
$$ Then if $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$, there exists $M'$ such that
$$
n > M' \implies x_n > M\,.
$$
Thus $n > M'$ implies $|f(x_n) - L| < \varepsilon$, which means that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = L$. Note that this holds for all sequences $\{x_n\}$ which diverge to infinity.

Assume now that for all sequences $\{x_n\}$ for which $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = L$. We want to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$. Assume the converse: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \neq L$. This means that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $M$ there exists $y_M > M$ such that
$$
|f(y_M) - L| \geq \varepsilon\,.
$$
Now let $y_n$ be such that $y_n > n$ and $|f(y_n) - L| \geq \varepsilon$ (these numbers exists by the above argument). Now $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence such that $y_n \to \infty$, but
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) \neq L\,.
$$
This is a contradiction, and thus we must have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$.

Comment: So $f(x_n)$ and $f(x)$ converge to the same value, but what about the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$? How can I form a sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$? And what is the difference between the sequence$\{f(x_n)\}$ and the function $f(x_n)$?

Comment: The function is $f$. Sometimes we are sloppy and say "the function $f(x)$" but actually  $f(x)$ should refer to the value of $f$ at a particular $x$. A  sequence  of reals should be considered to be a function $g$ from $N$ into $R$. E.g. the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in N} $ represents a function $g$ for which $g(n)=x_n$ for each $n$. Then the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\in N}$ represents a function $h$ where $h(n)=f(g(n))$ for each  $n$.

Comment: Oohhh thanks! I get it now